# How can I read answer of ionic BLE startnotification

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im noob on ionic and Im building my first app with BLE-CENTRAL. My problem is that when I made a suscription to a service, I dont know how to read the result data when this service is called.
I tried with this code, but doesnt work.

```
this.ble.startNotification(data.id,this.services[i].service,this.services[i].characteristic).subscribe(  buffer => { let data = new Uint32Array(buffer); this,this.showError(data[0])},() =>this.showError("FAIL") )
```

Showerror Method only shows an alert.

How can I read "buffer" or see all the data inside?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean look through actual array buffer?

Comment: Yep, I want to print it like an String or a String array

Comment: so what is shown when you do: this.showError(data)

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that It dont show anything and the .suscribe() shows the second method with the string "FAIL". It never shows the content of data

Comment: so fail means on error hook triggers, what error are you getting?

Comment: No one, this is my problem, I dont know how to read the return that .suscribe() give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your full implementation context, but since you see "FAIL" message, you should capture the error instead and see what's wrong:

```
this.ble.startNotification(data.id,this.services[i].service,this.services[i].characteristic).subscribe(
        (buffer) => { let data = new Uint32Array(buffer); this.showError(data) },
        (error) => this.showError(error)
    )
```

startNotifications method returns Observable, that means  your first method would return the result (buffer), second method can return error.

I added the code above so that you could at least read the error and then act from there.

Comment: I recieve "set notification failes for 00002a4e-0000-10000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

Comment: This usually means that your bluetooth server is setup improperly. Check to make sure that this characteristic has the notify property enabled on your server. Also, if available, make sure that the code used for notifications on the server is correct.